# How to make an modal with ejs and node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to learn a bit of ejs and node, I know that I can easily create a pop-up modal with only JS and HTML like this calling a function when I click certain button

Button to call the function:

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```

Function:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
   modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

But how can I do this with Ejs and NodeJs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It doesn't make sense to do this with EJS and Node**. In this context those are tools for running *server-side* code. It makes more sense to use the existing JS you have as client-side JavaScript (in the HTML document you are generating from the EJS).

That said, if you **really** wanted to do it server-side, then you'd want something like this in the HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <button name="modal" value="open">Open Modal</button>
</form>
```

And then (assuming you are using Express JS) something like:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.post("/your/page", function (req, res) {
    const show_modal = !!req.body.modal; // Cast to boolean
    res.render("page", { show_modal });
}
```

And then in the EJS:

```
<% if (show_modal) { %>
    <div id="modal" style="display: block">
        etc
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Ohh, thank you for the answer! Good to know that it doesn't make sense, I think that's why I didn't found any thing like that on google.